# Lua: io.read() doesn't work on long strings

Tags: io, lua

The following command freezes on a string of length about 2000 chars:

```
lua -e 'print(io.read())'
```

Any idea why?

PS: Lua version 5.1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most probably a limitation of terminal IO in the underlying operating system. It is enforced before it gets to the Lua limit.

Try entering a long line in `cat > /dev/null`.

Comment: You're totally right: the input freezes just as in case of my lua script. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

When called without arguments, `io.read` uses the default format `"*l"`, which reads the next line. The underlying buffer size is C's `BUFSIZ`, it seems that your input string has exceeded that limit.

Change it to `io.read("*a")` to read the whole input. Remember to send `EOF` in the end.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but unfortunately it stills freezes. What I also realized, the command freezes only on strings without any whitespace. Just a random text works perfectly.

Comment: For example, when I try to enter this string, I never get any response from lua: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7021941

Comment: @ChristianMüller I tested your example string on my machine and on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php, both work fine. I guess there's some hidden mystery somewhere.